# How will it happen when construct an object with the same object name

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

If the code entered a scope and defined a new object with the same name as the object outside, Will the newly defined object be correctly defined?
As following code shows:

```
class ClassB
{
    ClassA* p;
    ClassB(ClassA* a)
    {
         p = NULL;
         if (a != NULL)
               p = a;
    }
};

ClassA x;
if (some condition)
{
    ClassB x(x);
    // Will x->p be NULL or it will be pointer a?
}
```

In the if scope, x-> is NULL here or a? 
I can see in gcc, it will be NULL. But in VS2015 it seems a.
So my question is that what does the standard says for this part. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont do it. The fact that you have to ask here and that the answer isnt 100% obvious means that anybody else reading to code will also be confused by it. As as a purely academic question, it is interesting to know if it would work, but in any real code simply do this:

```
ClassA x;
if (some condition)
{
    ClassB y(&x);
}
```

Comment: i think question was rather if second x was initialized like int x{x}; would its value be value of first x or its value would be whatever it was before initialization

Comment: @AndrewKashpur tried to fix the answer. Now its rather a comment, but i'll just leave it unless it gets too many downvotes...